# My code won't execute the code block in the loop

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram extends Applet{
static int [] scores= {13,30,23,8};
static int [] minInterval = {0,25,50,75};
static int [] maxInterval = {25,50,75,100};
public void paint (Graphics g){
    int max = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (max < scores[i]) {
            max = scores[i];
        }
    }

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    Point2D.Double Yi = new Point2D.Double(50,50);
    Point2D.Double Yf = new Point2D.Double(50,30*scores.length);
    Line2D.Double Y = new Line2D.Double (Yi,Yf);
    Point2D.Double Xi = new Point2D.Double(50,50);
    Point2D.Double Xf = new Point2D.Double(50+(8*max),50);
    Line2D.Double X = new Line2D.Double (Xi,Xf);
    int x = 8*max;
    //Draw the "Score"
    int headerX = 50+(x/(max/5))*((max/5)-1);
    g2.drawString("Histogram of Student Scores",(headerX),30);
    for(int i=0;i<=max/5;i++){
        int j = (i)*5;
        if(i<max/5)
            g2.drawString(String.format("%d",j),50+(x/(max/5))*i,50);
        else
            g2.drawString(String.format("Number of Students"),50+(x/(max/5))*i,50);

    }
    for(int i=0;i<=maxInterval.length;i++){
        if(i != maxInterval.length-1 )
            g2.drawString(String.format("[%d,%d)",minInterval,maxInterval),20,60+(30)*i);
        else if(i == maxInterval.length-1)
            g2.drawString(String.format("[%d,%d]",minInterval,maxInterval),20,60+(30)*i);
        else
            g2.drawString("Score Ranges",20,60+(30)*i);
    }
    g2.draw(X);
    g2.draw(Y);
}

}
```

My problems is the code doesn't enter the third loop.but when i test the loop in another

method. it kinda work.so i don't know what to do next. and i want to know why it doesn't

execute that codeblock.

thank in advance.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute the second loop?

Comment: I would use a debugger - stick some break points in and see what's going on. It's much faster than asking on here, unless you have an SSCCE.

Comment: Can you verify max > 0 at that line?

Comment: I think `max/5` deserves a variable.

Comment: I'm  betting it does execute, but the graphics are being drawn beyond the visible pane's boundary.  Use a debugger to step through the code OR at least dump the values to System.out of the coordinates you are attempting to draw to.

Comment: @Bart Indeed this is why magic numbers are discouraged, store them in variables.

Answer (score 0):

You were supplying an array as a parameter to `String.format("...", , )` (instead of an `int`, which you get by looking up an element from the array, presumably with index `i`).

Since it was an argument to String.format, you most likely weren't getting a compiler or IDE warning.

So if you fix that, the code looks like this and you can take it from there.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxInterval.length; i++) {
        if (i != maxInterval.length - 1)
            g2.drawString(String.format("[%d,%d]", minInterval[i], maxInterval[i]), 20, 60 + (30) * i);
        else if (i == maxInterval.length - 1)
            g2.drawString(String.format("[%d,%d]", minInterval[i], maxInterval[i]), 20, 60 + (30) * i);
        else
            g2.drawString("Score Ranges", 20, 60 + (30) * i);
    }
```

Comment: I think "i <= maxInterval.length" should be "i < maxInterval.length"

Comment: It's not *copy/pasted*, it's *fixed* ;) ...point taken, I added an explanation